# Someone has closed my question, how can I unlock it?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

My question:”*Can I ask Allah To reverse time till the moment He Will Wants To Create Pen*” by a moderator. I know I have done 62 edits on it and too many wrongs in it. But this time I have the last plan to correct it in a proper manner; so can you unlock it? And after this, can anyone tell me if I have correct it in a proper manner? Really, I have learned my mistake and please do not give a ban message after I have edit it. Can you unlock it?

Comment: Absolutely none of your questions are currently locked.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided absolutely no evidence that your current "plan" is in any way an improvement. The question was deleted because countless edits were disrupting the site while not in any way making it clearer or more answerable, undeleting it so you can disrupt the site with *more* edits that may or may not be better is exactly the opposite of constructive right now.

If you want us to even *consider* undeleting the question, *edit the question first* (as was [already suggested to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303258/132874) on MSE) so the high-rep users in the community can review it. *Then* the community can decide whether or not it's worth undeleting.

Comment: How can I edit when it said “locked or closed”?

Comment: I tried to edit it, but then it shows me that I cannot edit it because it is locked.

Comment: And sorry for disturbing the site, I was only trying to improve in a proper manner, but this time O got another plan and I suppose it is a good one, and it is the last time I will edit.

Comment: Again: That question is *not* locked; no matter how much you beg, not even diamond moderators can unlock it since there's nothing *to* unlock. If you're getting a message telling you that it *is* locked, that is a bug and should be posted as a bug.

Comment: Oooo, I guess I understand now.

Comment: Oh, and what I do if I got on my question this [closed]?